# Nested condition of if-statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to check that of two variables *both or neither are set*. I've tried multiple options, and this is the most clean solution I've come up with:

```
if [ ! -z $A -a -z $B ] || [ -z $A -a ! -z $B ]; then
  #error
fi
  #success
```

When I run the script with both A and B set - it runs fine. But when I run it with A missing I get:

```
./test.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments
./test.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments
```

line 3 being the condition statement.

When I run it with B missing, I get:

```
./test.sh: line 3: [: argument expected
./test.sh: line 3: [: argument expected
```

Is it my condition that has wrong syntax or am I missing smth else?

Comment: Double quote the variables, otherwise if empty, they expand to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote your variables:

```
if [ ! -z "$A" -a -z "$B" ] || [ -z "$A" -a ! -z "$B" ]; then
```

If the variables are unquoted and unset, they are replaced with nothing, meaning that the command essentially becomes:

```
if [ ! -z -a -z ] || [ -z -a ! -z ]; then
```

resulting in the error you see.

Comment: kill me now... that simple?! 
Thanks, it works.

Comment: You might also mention `[[`, `&&` ... :)

Comment: @PesaThe: True, there are many options, depends on what shells/platforms are targeted..

Answer (score 9):

You should try to avoid `-a`; it's non-standard and considered obsolete by the POSIX standard. Since `||` and `&&` have equal precedence, you need to use `{ ... }` to properly group the individual tests.

(This is in addition to the immediate need to quote your parameter expansions.)

```
if { [ ! -z "$A" ] && [ -z "$B" ]; } || { [ -z "$A" ] && [ ! -z "$B" ]; }; then
```

However, a simpler expression might be

```
if [ -z "$A$B" ] || { [ "$A" ] && [ "$B" ]; }; then
```

1. The concatenation of two strings is empty if and only if both strings are also empty.
2. `[ "$A" ]` is short for `[ -n "$A" ]`, which is equivalent to `[ ! -z "$A" ]`.

---

Using `bash`'s `[[ ... ]]` command, you can write the more natural

```
if [[ -z $A && -n $B || -n $A && -z $B ]];
```

Quotes are optional in this case, and `||` and `&&` are usable inside `[[ ... ]]` with the precedence you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use quotation marks around your vars:

```
if [ ! -z "$A" -a -z "$B" ] || [ -z "$A" -a ! -z "$B" ]; then
    echo "error"
fi
```

Bash will replace your vars in your script with the values, so when `A=5` and `B` is unset, your version will read:

```
if [ ! -z 5 -a -z  ] || [ -z 5 -a ! -z ]; then
```

You see that the syntax is wrong, as `-z` expects an argument. When using quotes, is reads:

```
if [ ! -z "5" -a -z "" ] || [ -z "5" -a ! -z "" ]; then
```

AS you can see, now the argument for `B` is an empty string, which is valid.

Also your version would have failed when setting `A="string with spaces"` when unquoted.